# Using OData Filter with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, odata

I'm developing a application that use $filter of odata with Java Spring Boot and didn't find something that help implement this.

Filter System Query Option ($filter) https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Is there any library that converts the oData standard to be used in Java Spring Data JPA?

Ex.:
/Products?$filter=Price gt 20 or name = 'test' and (type = 'abc' or category = 'bca')

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private String type;
    private String category;

}
```

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {
    
}
```

I already try to use JpaSpecificationExecutor, Querydsl and Specifications.